# Error upgrading to Rails 3.2 with Paperclip: write_inheritable_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm upgrading an app from Rails 3.1 to 3.2 and I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for #<Class:0x0000010a190dd8>):
  app/models/test_file.rb:37:in `<class:TestFile>'
  app/models/test_file.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/models/ability.rb:44:in `initialize'
```

The error applies to this model code:

```
has_attached_file :logo,  
:styles => {:medium => "300x200>", :thumb => "150x60>" },  
:storage => :s3,  
:s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",  
:path => "/logos/:style/:id/:filename"
```

I have no instances of `write_inheritable_attribute` anywhere in my app's code. If the above is removed, the error repeats for the next instance of similar code in the app (i.e. everywhere Paperclip is used).

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rmagick'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

I think this issue *may* be with Paperclip's internal code somewhere. Do you know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",